# Spring boot REST API to accept call only from Angular Front End

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am a newbie in Spring boot rest api.

I have the following scenarios in place:

1. KeyCloak already installed and configured for authentication
2. Spring Boot microservices
3. Angular front end

The Angular makes calls to microservices through Spring Cloud gateway.

I have designed my own login page which uses KeyCloak to authenticate and get a token.  That works fine.

Is there any way to allow making calls to the microservices only from Angular using a general token for unregistered users?

Why i want this, is to secure the microservices from being accessed directly from any other tools like postman.

Any guide/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want to give access to unregistered users access to certain pages. Say any users can access login page and login end point even if they have not registered. For this case usually we don't need to have any token mechanism, instead you can have an **IP throttling mechanism where if the users access the web page N times in X minutes block that ip for Y minutes.** This is what is done usually to prevent ddos attack.

There is no way to completely prevent access from POSTMAN, because any browser requests can be mocked by POSTMAN by adding certain headers or other parameters, even if you have some tokens in place for unregistered users.

Comment: Lets say an unregistered user is browsing the website, and viewing the list of products.  So the list of products is being fetch through a call to a microservice.   So is there any way to get a token directly from KeyCloak without login in and that when the call is being done, the token is passed in the header to the microservice.  Thus, in a sense we are ensuring that they call is being made from the angular itself.  Maybe am wrong here, but need some clarification if its achievable.  Many thanks

Comment: Yes you are right, But not all apis needs to have prior login/token authentication. Take a look at Amazon/Flipkart's search apis, you can inspect flipkart's search end point on network tab, there is no auth token required for those apis. Because they are openly available. When it comes to purchasing an item you can have a login, not for searching. You should exclude those apis from being authenticated using token

Comment: To avoid overusing you can add IP throttling/cors policies..etc

Comment: Thanks Justin, agreed the cors policies can be implemented to restrict access to the API through web browser as far as i have understood.  But still, the API can be accessed by other means such as POstman by others.

Comment: As long as a browser can access call this api's , POSTMAN can call irrespective of what every restriction you put in. If there is a way to detect the call is coming from a particular application then its possible, But in case of postman we cant ensure it will send us some properties, or headers to differenciate . Because its a third party tool, and it is a dev tool and no way we can recognize this at server side and block as of now. I dont think its a required implementation from POSTMAN side also.

Answer (score 0):

Calls from the angular application to the backend microservices through your browser can be easily executed using tools like curl, POSTMAN, httpie. We cannot stop that.

Even if you think getting a token without supplying credentials for unregistered users and angular making calls to background microservices with that token to a specific API would solve that issue. Very easily anyone can obtain a token from their browser as an unregistered user and use that token to make calls from tools like POSTMAN, curl. So we cannot stop calls from those tools

All you can do is mitigate the attack by using CORS, API-Throttling